# xpath - how to find info

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

Given this HTML:

```
<tr class="even" id="district_22">
    <td class="name">Virginia Beach City Public Schools</td>
    <td class=""><a href="/admin/districts/22" class="member_link delete_link" data-confirm="Sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" id="district_23">
    <td class="name">Virginia City City Public Schools</td>
    <td class=""><a href="/admin/districts/23" class="member_link delete_link" data-confirm="Sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" id="district_24">
    <td class="name">Virginia Town City Public Schools</td>
    <td class=""><a href="/admin/districts/24" class="member_link delete_link" data-confirm="Sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to use Selenium and xpath with it.
I am having problems when trying to select the 'delete' link that belongs to 'Virginia Beach City Public Schools'.
I am new to xpath.

I am trying:

```
xpath=(//td[text()='Beach')]/@class.contains('delete'))
```

but it is not finding the element.

Note: I cannot use the ID as these are repeated tests and the ID changes each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Beach')]/../td/a[contains(@class,'delete_link')]
```

Comment: Just to explain what's going on... the first bit of the xpath selects the td that contains 'beach'. It then selects that td's parent and from there selects any td that contains a link that has a class containing 'delete_link'. Hope that makes it clear!

Answer (score 1):

`tr[@id="district_22"]//a[contains(@class,'delete_link')]`  would be a lot better.
It's not good to look at the text. After all it may get localized and edited in other ways. ID's however are ment to be unchanging and not duplicated.

Comment: Sorry that doesn not work for me.  I am running automated tests and using xpath in them.  I set up and tear down (i.e. delete) my objects each time.  The database sequences continue to incrment though so I actually need a way to do it by name without referring to ID's which change with each run.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, I see. Anyway, since you create the item and you know the full name then get by the full name: `td[text()='Virginia Beach City Public Schools')]/...` otherwise you might get multiple 'Beach' results

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to execute a automate scripts in loop, if this is the case then you can try the below code:

```
 for(i=1,dist=22; i<-count; i++,dist++)
 {
    ....
    ....
    driver..findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=District_"+dist+"]/..."))
 }
```